# cant get my index page to show my products data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-handlebars

i cant get my saved data from my product seeder to the store correctly

it looks like this https://prnt.sc/t0ys47

and i want the image and the titles from the data i have come to the page

```
{{# each products}}

<div class="row">
{{# each this}}

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="{{this.imagePath}}" alt="..." class = "img-responsive">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3 align="center">{{this.title}}</h3>
    <p class="description">{{this.description}}</p>
        <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="price pull-left">€{{this.price}}<ahref="#" style="float:right"class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">Add cart</a> </div>

         </div>
    </div>

    </div>

{{/each}}

</div>

{{/each}}
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/product');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 Product.find(function(err, docs) {
var productChunks = [];
var chunkSize = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
      productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
}
res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: productChunks });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Are there any errors being logged to the console?

Comment: no it dont have any error in console